# Are they any server-side configurations required to use ajax?

Tags: ajax, web-deployment

I'm interested in using ajax, so i wonder if my server have to satisfy some requirements to use ajax, or is ajax completly client-side and works e.g with a default apache2 configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no server side configuration required to execute the ajax.
The essence of AJAX is this:
Your pages can browse the web and update their own content while the user is doing other things.

That is, your javascript can send asynchronous GET and POST requests (usually via an XMLHttpRequest object) then use the results of those requests to modify its page (via Document Object Model manipulation).

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is acting like an HTTP request you can make on your browser. If the url works with browser, it will works using Ajax